# What does the first semicolon imply? " ;( function( ) { } ) ( ); "

Tags: javascript, iife

I was just going through the [source code of cordova.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/CordovaLib/cordova.js), its structure is like

```
;(function() { cordova code I have yet to understand })();
```

Just curious what does the first semi-colon imply?

Is it just to make sure that there is a semicolon preceding the anonymous function or does it mean something else?

Comment: Implies that the author wants to make sure any previous statement is successfully terminated. Especially useful when combining several JS files into one. The `()` in JavaScript can be interpreted as the postfix "call" operator, which most likely yield an undesired behavior on the result of a previous expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a defensive semicolon, this is in case someone concatenates some JavaScript before your code, and this concatenated code forgot to put a terminating semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

It's just to prevent an error if you combine multiple js files. So you can remove it if you want.